# Is there a library for large precision complex numbers in Python?

Tags: python, complex-numbers, largenumber

Is there a library for large precision complex numbers in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) which offers real and complex floating-point arithmetic with arbitrary precision.

Comment: @eddie Is this useful to you? Would be nice to get some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try numpy ([official website](https://numpy.org/)).

Comment: Does numpy do arbitrary precision floating point?

Comment: Hmm, looking at the documentation, it looks like it supports up to 256 bit complex numbers (two 128 floats), supposing your platform supports it.  Since numpy has a certain focus on speed, looks like you're limited to what can be supported natively by your computer.